# How to extract a region shape from an 2 colour image?

Tags: graphics, image-processing, word-cloud

I'll start by saying that I don't know anything about image processing. I have an image and I need to extract its outermost shape for use in a `WordCloud`. The image only has two colours and the outermost shape is a boundary between the two colours. A representative image follows (but the colours are not black and white in the actual image).

[image]

With this image I would expect the region calculated to be the union of the disk and rounded corner rectangle.  Again, this only representative and the actual image is not made of an union of basic shapes.

I believe that if I call the image processing equivalent of `DiscretizeGraphics` and get many points then I could take the convex hull of this set of points and use this region in a `WordCloud`. `DiscretizeGraphics` doesn't work on JPEG and `EdgeDetect` does not return an object compatible with `DiscretizeGraphics`.

May someone point me in the correct direct to do this on an image? If this is not the best approach please offer alternatives.

Comment: The intersection? Are you sure? It will be very difficult to calculate the intersection of two shapes that aren't completely specified (in the general case, I mean)

Comment: @belisariushassettled Sorry, the union.  Late night in the office. I'll update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only want the interior black areas filled? Then you just need a `FillingTransform`:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUfE7.jpg"];
FillingTransform[img]
```

[image]

Or, if you want a binary result for a color image: `FillingTransform[Binarize[img]]` (which looks the same in this case, because the source image already is black and white)

Answer (score 13):

```
i  = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUfE7.jpg"];
m  = SelectComponents[i, "EmbeddedComponents", Length[#] === 0 &];
i1 = FillingTransform[i, Dilation[m, 1]];
m1 = SelectComponents[ColorNegate@i1, "EmbeddedComponents", Length[#] === 0 &];
i2 = FillingTransform[i1, Dilation[m1, 1]];
{{i, m, i1, m1, i2}} // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Edit**

The following supports more general images:

```
f[x_Image] := FixedPoint[Module[{m, i1, m1},
    m = SelectComponents[#, "EmbeddedComponents", Length[#] === 0 &];
    i1 = FillingTransform[#, Dilation[m, 1]];
    m1 = SelectComponents[ColorNegate@i1, "EmbeddedComponents", Length[#] === 0 &];
    FillingTransform[i1, Dilation[m1, 1]]
    ] &, Binarize@x]

i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu7yt.png"];
{{i, f@i}} // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Edit**

Here is another non-recursive way:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu7yt.png"];
i1 = ImageMultiply[i, ColorNegate@
       Image[Plus @@ (ComponentMeasurements[i, {"EnclosingComponents", "Mask"}, 
                                            # != {} &][[All, 2, 2]])]];
m = SelectComponents[i1, "EmbeddedComponents", Length[#] === 0 &];
i1 = FillingTransform[i1, Dilation[m, 1]];

{{i, f@i}} // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: There are some very informative approaches presented. (+1) However, @nikie one-liner is easier to explain to others and manage.

Comment: @Edmund Of course. I made up that because I found corner cases where FilliTransform wasn't enough. Trying to remember what were those :)